# API Pagination and search with Symfony and React: Best Practice

Tags: php, reactjs, symfony

I am working on a Fullstack App with Symfony 6.4 and React.js. I have a conceptual question about pagination and search.

**Pagination**

I implemented pagination using Symfony, ensuring that the API always retrieves 10 items per pagination. This setup functions perfectly. However, is it considered good practice to call the API every time the pagination is switched?  The second question about pagination, that Sort By is in this case going to work only on 10 entries.

Question 1: Is it better to get all data from database, and make the sort by and pagination on client side? Or it is better to do it on server side? The Table could have lot of entries

CustomeRepository

```
class CustomerRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository
{
   public function __construct(ManagerRegistry $registry)
   {
       parent::__construct($registry, Customer::class);
   }

   public function getCustomers(
       string $column,
       string $type,
       int    $page = 1,
       int    $entriesPerPage = 10): array
   {
       $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('d')
           ->orderBy("d.$column", $type)
           ->getQuery();
       $paginator = new Paginator($query);
       $paginator->getQuery()
           ->setFirstResult($entriesPerPage * ($page - 1))
           ->setMaxResults($entriesPerPage);
       $total = $paginator->count();
       $lastPage = (int)ceil($total / $entriesPerPage);

       return [
           'customers' => $paginator,
           'lastPage' => $lastPage,
           'total' => $total
       ];

   }
}
```

CustomerController

```
    #[Route(path: "/api/customer/{column}/{type}/{page}", name: "customer_get", methods: ["GET"])]
    public function getCustomer(
        CustomerService $customerService,
        string $column,
        string $type,
        int $page=1
    ): JsonResponse
    {
        return $this->json($customerService->getCustomers($column, $type, $page));
    }
```

**Search**

Question 2: So far Search was done in Client Side. Is it better to do it on Server Side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, it's always better to perform sort,pagination, and search on the server side rather than the client side, and there are very good reasons behind this:

- **client-side limited processing power:** You should assume that the client device doesn't have much computational power because it's a device with very limited resources, so the client device will probably hang and lag if it is asked to process a huge amount of data.
- **server-side operations have better performance:** When you retrieve data from your database, if you want to paginate the results then the query builder will use MySQL `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` statements to cut exactly the amount of data you need instead of having to split it on the client side, and if you want to sort the data then the query builder will use MySQL `ORDER BY` statement to do this instead of sorting it manually on the client side. If you want to search inside the data then the query builder will use a MySQL `WHERE` statement to perform the search for you instead of having to search for specific data on the client side. Aside from all that, you can optimize your database and use indices to speed up these operations even more.
- **send only the data that the client is interested in:** The client may need a few specific entries, but if you send the contents of an entire database table to the client side then you're sending him data that he may not need or use at all. This point is important because the response body can become very large, and the client might wait for a long time before fully receiving the response, especially on slow network connections and limited data plans.

> Is it considered good practice to call the API every time the pagination is switched?

Usually, there's no problem with that. However, you could send a reasonable amount of data such that the user doesn't have to use pagination very much. For example, on each page send 50 entries at once, and maybe you can cache the previous page when the user moves to the next one (although I'm not sure if this can be done since I'm not a React developer, but still)

---

**A side important note:** You may be vulnerable to SQL injection attacks on this line:

```
$query = $this->createQueryBuilder('d')
       ->orderBy("d.$column", $type)
       ->getQuery();
```

Because you're passing the column name as a variable, and these parts of an SQL query can't use query binds. For more information please consult the
[SQL Injection Prevention](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html#defense-option-3-allow-list-input-validation) page on OWASP cheatsheet website.